# How To open Sub Menu with onclick Function and hide with onclick Function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a sidebar nav I did this so on mouseover opens sub menu but I want it on click to open and onclick on same tab to hide it. Please check my code in this codepen Thanks.

```
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erNpYG

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: And what is your attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: yes check codepen please i used hover to open sub menu i want onclick function to open sub menu and onclick to hide submenu. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please mention the relevant Javascript code you wrote to solve this problem.

Comment: yes i didn't know the javascript well for solve this issue :(

Comment: First learn Javascript and then this could be one way to start learning about `onclick`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick Once you attempt to solve your problem but are stuck somewhere, you are welcome to ask a question here

Answer (score 5):

You can use a hidden checkbox with the [general sibling combinator (`~`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) to close and open the sub menu on click without javascript:

```css
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.navigation {
  width: 300px;
}
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mainmenu a, .mainmenu label {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}
.mainmenu a:hover, .mainmenu label:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

/* hide the input */
.mainmenu input {
  display: none;
}
/* if a sibling checkbox is check show the menu */
.mainmenu input:checked ~ .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.submenu a, .submenu label {
  background-color: #999;
}
.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}
.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="products">
      <label for="products">Products</label>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: CSS Solution. I loved it. +1 for the non JS answer.

Comment: Smooth and creative.

Comment: Yes its a great solution without use of js. But how would it be if we will have multiple dropdown. We should close the another dropdown when clicked on another. I think Js is much required.

Comment: @AnmolSandal - you actually don't need JS for this answer because " i want on click open submenu and onclick on same tab it's hide".

Comment: I totally agree with your answer. But actually i am talking about multiple dropdowns. like we have a dropdown for about tab too. Then user want to open submenu for about then we should close the submenu of products.

Comment: The css answer could also have the `-webkit-transition`  property unprefixed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you out. I have added some jquery. Used Id for the target submenu. You can repeat it for others too. Just need to change id. I have created one example for about tab too. here on click of another tab the other tab menu will shut down.

```js
$('.dropdown').click(function () {
  var target_id = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
  $('.dropdown-list').not(target_id).slideUp();
  $(target_id).slideToggle();
  $('.dropdown-list').not(target_id).parents('li, .icon-tab').removeClass('active');
  $('.dropdown').not(this).parents(' .icon-tab').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parents('li, .icon-tab').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
.navigation {
  width: 300px;
}

/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

/* add hover behaviour */
.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
  display the submenu inside it.
  we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
*/

/*
  we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
  CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
*/

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}

/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
  we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
*/
.submenu {
 
 display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown" data-toggle="#about">About</a>
      <ul class="submenu dropdown-list" id="about">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown" data-toggle="#products">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu dropdown-list" id="products">
        <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.dropdown').each(function() {
          var $dropdown = $(this);

          $(".dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $div = $(".submenu", $dropdown);
            $div.toggle();
            $(".submenu").not($div).hide();
            return false;
          });

        });

        $('html').click(function(){
          $(".submenu").hide();
        });

      });
```

```css
html, body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        /* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
        .navigation {
          width: 300px;
        }

        /* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */
        .mainmenu, .submenu {
          list-style: none;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }

        /* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
        .mainmenu a {
          display: block;
          background-color: #CCC;
          text-decoration: none;
          padding: 10px;
          color: #000;
        }

        /* add hover behaviour */
        .mainmenu a:hover {
            background-color: #C5C5C5;
        }


        /* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
          display the submenu inside it.
          we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
        */

        /*
          we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
          CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
        */

        .submenu a {
          background-color: #999;
        }

        /* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
        .submenu a:hover {
          background-color: #666;
        }

        /* this is the initial state of all submenus.
          we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
        */
        .submenu {
          overflow: hidden;
          display: none;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">About</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Products</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Other dropdown</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Tops</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bottoms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Footwear</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: this is using jquery not vanilla js.

Comment: @HTML CSS Hupp Technologies I have noticed many times in your answer, you are not at all giving any explanation about your code like what changes you have done, why your solution is working and what is the problem on his mehtod and etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is using pure JS

**CSS**

```
.subrollin{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.subrollout{
  overflow: block;
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

**JS**

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('parentmenu')[0];
element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
var sub = document.getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0];
  if(sub.classList.contains('subrollout')){
      sub.classList.add("subrollin");    
      sub.classList.remove("subrollout");
  } else {
      sub.classList.add("subrollout");
      sub.classList.remove("subrollin");
  }
}, false);
```

see this codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzpaer